# copy big file to multiple locations at the same time

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, file-transfer, xcopy, copy

I am trying to use a CMD command prompt to copy a big file (1.5G) from one location to multiple destinations at the same time. Is there a way to do this using `COPY`/`XCOPY` etc? I haven't been able to get this work using this type of command:

```
copy "c:\test\*.*" "e:" & copy "c:\test\*.*" "f:" & copy "c:\test\*.*" "g:"
```

It seems like this should work but it works step by step like e: -> f: -> g:

Any advice is greatly appreciated! I would like to avoid a batch file because of the way this needs to be implemented. or it there other good idea?

Comment: I will advice robocopy its powerful

Comment: I don't know an answer to your question,  but, in CMD, you should expect *`cmd1`* `& ` *`cmd2`* `& ` *`cmd3`* to be the same as *`cmd1`* <Enter> (and wait) *`cmd2`* <Enter> (and wait) *`cmd3`* <Enter> (and wait); i.e., sequential execution.

Answer (score -1):

In order to do this, you can use the `start` command, which launches the command separately and would allow you to run these commands in parallel.

In `cmd`, you could run something along these lines:

```
start "" copy C:\test*. E:
start "" copy C:\test*. F:
```

and so on and so forth...

However, it may be worth it to consider utilizing PowerShell instead. You could probably create an identical result by doing something like this:

```
$sourceDir = "C:\test\"
$destDir = "E:\","F:\","G:"

$destDir | Foreach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $sourceDir -Dest $_ }
```

Comment: thank you for answering so much!  i would test it soon!  what does “” means?

Comment: Please correct your answer to use normal quotes and **not** smart quotes (which break the script).